# How to define the environment variable in environments url [Gitlab CI]

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, environment

Help, please. I have problems when using the CI tool.

Here's my `.gitlab-ci.yaml`

```
stages:
  - test

test:
  stage: test
  environment:
    name: test
    url: https://word.mymusise.com/env_test.txt
  script: echo "Running tests TEST=$TEST"
```

And I've define the `test` environment in `EnvDocker > Pipelines > Environments`

But it didn't export the environment from `https://word.mymusise.com/env_test.txt` in the CI job.

```
Running with gitlab-runner 11.4.2 (cf91d5e1)
  on gitlab-ci runner a0e18516
Using Docker executor with image ubuntu:16.04 ...
Pulling docker image ubuntu:16.04 ...
Using docker image sha256:2a697363a8709093834e852b26bedb1d85b316c613120720fea9524f0e98e4a2 for ubuntu:16.04 ...
Running on runner-a0e18516-project-123-concurrent-0 via gitlab...
Fetching changes...
HEAD is now at d12c05b Update .gitlab-ci.yml
From https://gitlab.kingdomai.com/mymusise/envdocker
   d12c05b..1a3954f  master     -> origin/master
Checking out 1a3954f8 as master...
Skipping Git submodules setup
$ echo "Running tests TEST=$TEST"
Running tests TEST=
Job succeeded
```

I define `export TEST="test"` in `https://word.mymusise.com/env_test.txt`, but it seems not working.

What should I do... Orz

Gitlab version: 11.4.0-ee

Comment: You need to do that manually. Why would expect gitlab to do it for you? `$(curl "$url")`.

Comment: @KamilCuk Thanks, but how to do that manually? Yes, I hope gitlab do it for me. Should I add `$(curl "$url")` in script ? If do that, what‘s `environment: name: test url: $url` do

Answer (score 1):

You want to run commands that are inside the text file that is accessible via http protocol.

With `curl` you can download the file and print it on `curl`'s standard output. With command substitution `$()` you can grab the standard output. Then you can execute the commands itself (very unsafe, there might be multiple escaping issues).

```
 script: 
   - $(curl "$url")
   - echo "Running tests TEST=$TEST"
```

A safer alternative would be to just download the file and execute/source it.

```
 script: 
   - curl "$url" > ./run_this.sh
   # don't forget to add executable right to the file ;)
   - chmod +x ./run_this.sh
   - source ./run_this.sh
   # pick out the trash
   - rm ./run_this.sh
   # rest of your script.
   - echo "Running tests TEST=$TEST"
```

Downloading a shell script and executing it is a popular way of automating tasks, usually with `curl url | bash`. It is not supported "natively" by gitlab and I don't think it should be.

Comment: Thanks! It's a good way to load my environment with `curl url | bash`. But I still wonder what `Gitlab CI` do in protecting the environment. (Protected Environments)[https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/environments/protected_environments.html]

Comment: May I ask how did you manage the configuration in different environments (test, build, deploy)

Comment: I aim not to have anything complex and have scripts that I can fully run  at my own computer, so I can test them before commit, usually with as few variables/parameters as I can get. My projects are C-ish, so it just "build"s with cmake, sometimes it tests, there really is no  "environment" that can affect it. For deploy, really what is needed is a private ssh key stored as a hidden variable in gitlab passed to stdin of the script and server address passed as an argument.